# Проблема с запуском Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Пытаюсь открыть Eclipse для Java. Выдает лог ошибки(текстовый файл) примерно такого содержания

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_PRIV_INSTRUCTION (0xc0000096) at pc=0x000000005e8f62d1, pid=4408, tid=0x0000000000000840
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x662d1]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: попробуйте переустановить Java и Eclipse.  добавьте в вопрос информацию о вашем окружении - версия ОС, информация о компьютере и пр.

Comment: Какова у вас битность Eclipse? Должна соответствовать установленной версии Java, в вашем случае 64-bit.